# Одновременный пуш в гит с 2 компьютеров

Tags: git

Что будет при одновременном "пуше" в один репозиторий с 2-ух разных компьютеров. Выдаст ошибку обоим или только одному?

Comment: нет возможности проверить, а узнать хочется

Comment: Здесь одновременности не бывает. Есть два пуша в очереди, вот и обработаны будут по очереди. И не важно, интервал там 1 наносекунда или 1 день.

Comment: еще тогда вопрос, а если будет третий юзер, который начнет делать pull, то он тоже встанет в очередь? начнется загрузка после предыдущих пушей?

Comment: Да. Все работает через очереди.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

операция *push* представляет собой последовательность двух глобальных шагов:

1. загрузка новых (отсутствующих на сервере) коммитов
2. передвижение указателя (общепринятое его название — ветка/branch) со «старого» коммита на «новый».

передвижение указателя — операция атомарная. первый, кто попытается передвинуть указатель (с позиции *a* в позицию *б*) — **сможет** это осуществить (естественно, если в процессе не возникнет каких-то ошибок, например, при выполнении соответствующих hook-ов). второй же, кто попытается предвинуть указатель (с той же позиции *а*, но уже в другую позицию — *в*), получит ошибку: ведь указатель к этому моменту будет находиться уже не в позиции *а*, а в позиции *б*.

> а если будет третий юзер, который начнет делать pull, то он тоже встанет в очередь?

зависит от реализации сервера. с точки зрения блокировок — операция *pull* — не блокирующая (в отличие от операции *push*), потому может быть реализовано и параллельное выполнение шагов, из которых состоят операции *push* и *pull*.

p.s. глобальные шаги, из которых состоит операция *pull*:

1. получение текущего значения запрашиваемого указателя
2. запрос и получение всех недостающих (у клиента) коммитов, чтобы выстроить цепочку, вершиной которой является коммит, на который и ссылается новое значение указателя.